# Multiple messages from Xamarin Messaging center when application is restarted

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a `Xamarin Forms` application in which I use `MessagingCenter` to send some data from specific platform to `Xamarin.Forms` application.

In my `Page` I subscribe to messages in `base.OnAppearing()` and unsubscribe in `base.OnDisappearing()` method. This works as expected.

The problem I'm having is that when application get's stopped by the `AndroidOS` (example of this is when I change the language of device) I start getting copies of messages. I'm confused why this is happening but I noticed that `base.OnDisappearing()` method is not called when application is restarted.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause my problem and how to fix it?
Also, is there any way in `Xamarin` to see all your publishers and subscribers?

Comment: If the calls to `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` are not balanced, that's a bug. I recommend to file a report at bugzilla.xamarin.com with a self contained example.

Comment: Workaround here might be to always call unsubscribe before subscribing agian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to not be directly related with Xamarin.Forms, but was due to a problem of not properly unregistering the `BroadcastReceiever` in the `OnStop` method inside my `MainActivity` class. So whenever the application went through `OnStop/OnStart` cycle, 2 messages would be sent, even though I had only one active subscription.

I also call `Unsubsribe` in my `OnDisappearing` method on Xamarin.Forms ContentPages, and also call `Unsubscribe` before calling `Subscribe` in `OnAppearing` method.

So far I haven't had this issue again on any of devices or different Android versions.

And some additional advice, don't ever forget to Unsubscribe any remaining MessagingCenter subscriptions you have in the OnDisappearing method otherwise you are in for some weird bugs, that will make your hair turn gray. There was a nice article on that topic, but I can't find it again.

Answer (score 3):

Like Greensy said, in addition to subscribing in `OnAppearing()` and unsubscribing in `OnDisappearing()`, I also unsubscribe from the message before subscribing because, why not:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing() {
    base.OnAppearing();

    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<string>(this, "KeyHere");
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "KeyHere", string => { }));
}
```

Comment: I will try your solution tomorrow. It's kind of annoying that Xamarin does not have any "is subscribed" check method.

Comment: Sadly this does not work for me. I still get multiple messages after changing the language on device (and the app gets reloaded or something). I tried checking my navigation stack and there are no duplicate pages. So I have no idea where my duplicates are comming from.

Comment: @DenisVitez Maybe try adding `Debug.WriteLine()` message before and after the subscription to see if those get run multiple times? If all else fails you could also just put the MessagingCenter subscription into the page's constructor. As long as you do not do it too much, it should not be too big of a problem. I know Android loves screwing up the `OnAppearing()`/`OnDisappearing()` flow, which causes lots of issues. You may still want to submit a bug report about this one though

Comment: I've noticed that if you send messages from an object you've bound in a bindingcontext ( like a viewmodel ) and listen for the message in the parent page you get duplicated messages. Not sure if that helps..

Comment: @chad An ugly solution might be to unsubscribe from the `MessagingCenter` event within `MainActivity.OnSaveInstanceState()` which should get called before the OS destroys everything.

Comment: @hvaughan3 I've began wondering about an object being garbage collected before unsubscribing. I'm not sure it's possible since i'm new to c# but imagine a subscribed object being garbage collected without unsubscribing then a new instance of the same object subscribing. It would make sense the object wouldn't be double subscribed since the references are different but maybe there's a bug in the message center and subscriptions by a type are mapped to the current instance of that type even if one, or more, are stale.

Comment: @chad Yea I do not know enough about it either to say. I think a subscribed event might work a little different but again I am not sure. On Android anything is possible though. Certain Android manufacturers have some very very strange quirks about them and can be widely different from other manufacturers even among the same version of Android which is unfortunate.

Comment: @hvaughan3 what i've been doing is any message subscription done in a constructor gets an unsub in the finalizer (destructor) plus unsub prior to any subscribe everywhere else. that seems to have fixed the issue for me

Comment: @chad Nice, thanks for letting me know. I forget about the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Forms v2.3.4.247, on Android, in testing, we found that when a modal page was on top of a navigation page, and you leave the app, the navigation page had its OnDisappearing() method called instead of the modal page that is actually on top.
To work around, we did the following:
- In the OnAppearing method, check if you're actually on top
- if you are on top, all good
- if you're not on top, call SendDisappearing() on yourself, and SendAppearing() on the actual page on top. We also found that you needed to call SendDisappearing() on the page on top, since Xamarin forms protects these methods from multiple calls. In other words, if you call SendDisappearing() twice, it will only do something once.

Here's an example which worked for us, as we have a BaseContentPage from which all pages are derived:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    var pageOnTop = ModalContentPageOnTop();
    if (pageOnTop == null || pageOnTop == this)
    {
        // do some stuff, like setting up subscriptions
        SetupSubscriptions();
    }
    else
    {
        // Xamarin Forms Appearing/Disappearing Bug
        // Found that when you leave the Android app with a modal page on top of a non-modal page (either minimise the app or lock the device), then Xamarin.Forms does not properly call OnAppearing. 
        // Xamarin.Forms will call OnAppearing on the non-modal page and not on the modal page. This would not only cause message subscriptions to not be set up on the modal page, 
        // but would also set up message subscriptions on the non-modal page. Not good.  Hopefully, this work-around should stop being executed when Xamarin fixes the problem, as we won't 
        // fall into this "else" condition above, because OnAppearing will be called on the right page.

        // NOTE: SendDisappearing and SendAppearing have boolean guards on them. If SendAppearing was called last, calling it again will do nothing.
        // SendDisappearing has the same behaviour. Thus we need to call SendDisappearing first, to be guaranteed that SendAppearing will cause the OnAppearing() method to execute.
        ((IPageController)pageOnTop).SendDisappearing();  // try and correct Xamarin.Forms - the page actually on top was not told it was disappearing - tell it now
        ((IPageController)this).SendDisappearing();  // try and correct Xamarin.Forms - if it thinks the view has appeared when it hasn't, it won't call OnAppearing when it is truly appearing.
        ((IPageController)pageOnTop).SendAppearing();  // try and correct Xamarin.Forms by notifying the correct page that it is appearing
    }
}
```

where ModalContentPageOnTop looks like:

```
private ContentPage ModalContentPageOnTop()
{
    var page = Navigation.ModalStack.LastOrDefault();
    var navigationPage = page as NavigationPage;
    if (navigationPage != null)
        return navigationPage.CurrentPage as ContentPage;
    return page as ContentPage;
}
```

We had a very shallow navigation hierarchy in our app, so this approach may not work with more complicated navigation stacks (ie modal pages that push other pages or other modal pages)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` you could subscribe to it after `InitializeComponent()` in the page constructor and unsubscribe like so:

```
protected override void OnParentSet()
{
    base.OnParentSet();

    if (Parent == null)
    {
        // unsubscribe 
    }
}
```

`OnParentSet` gets called before `OnAppearing` and after `OnDisappearing`. However, the Parent only becomes null on a Page after it is removed from the navigation stack or when popping the page. This ensures they both only get called once while I've noticed `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` aren't always called consistently depending on how pop-ups and/or other things might be shown.