# Xamarin Viewmodel are not destroyed when android application is destroyed

Tags: xamarin.forms

In ContentPage constructor,
`BindingContext = new OrdersViewModel();`

When App is exited by pressing back button and appears again then contentpage is created again and new viewmodel is created but previous instance of viewmodel is not destroyed.
Previous viewmodel should be destroyed.

Is this the issue with Xamarin? Is there a solution?

```
public class OrdersViewModel
{ 
    public OrdersViewModel()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IRepositoryService, List<FirestoreOrderDetail>>(this, "ORDERS", (s, o) =>
            {
                Task.Run(() => LoadOrders(o));
            });
        
            Task.Run(() => ExecuteLoadOrdersCommand()); 
    
        }
    public async Task ExecuteLoadOrdersCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            try
            {
        //OrderRepository calls Android OrderRepository through DependencyService
        //Android OrderRepository creates a sanpshotlistener.
        //Snapshotlistener generates events which this viewmodel subscribed in constructor.
                await OrderRepository.GetItemsAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
}

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Shop.Droid.Repositories.FireStore.OrderRepository))]
namespace Shop.Droid.Repositories.FireStore
{
    public class OrderRepository : Java.Lang.Object, IOrders//, IOnCompleteListener, Firebase.Firestore.IEventListener
    {
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var collection = Firebase.Firestore.FirebaseFirestore.Instance.Collection(Constants.DataObjectName_Orders);
                Query ordersForShopQuery = collection.WhereEqualTo("Id", GlobalThings.ProfileId);
                    
                if (GlobalThings.OrderRepoistoryListenerForShopRegistration == null)
                {
                    listner = new OrderRepoistoryListenerForShop();
                    listenerRegistration = ordersForShopQuery.AddSnapshotListener(listner);
                    GlobalThings.OrderRepoistoryListenerForShopRegistration = listenerRegistration;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log exception
            }

            return null;
        }
}

namespace Shop.Droid.Repositories.FireStore
{
    public class OrderRepoistoryListenerForShop : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener,            Firebase.Firestore.IEventListener,IRepositoryService
    {
        public void OnComplete(Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task)
        {
            if (task.IsSuccessful)
            {
                var querySnapshot = (QuerySnapshot)task.Result;
                ProcessDocuments(querySnapshot);
            }
        }
        public void OnEvent(Java.Lang.Object obj, Firebase.Firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException error)
        {
            var querySnapshot = (QuerySnapshot)obj;
            ProcessDocuments(querySnapshot);
        }

        private void ProcessDocuments(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot)
        {
            List<FirestoreOrderDetail> firestoreOrderDetails = new List<FirestoreOrderDetail>();
            foreach (var doc in querySnapshot.Documents)
            {
               //
            }

            MessagingCenter.Send<IRepositoryService, List<FirestoreOrderDetail>>(this, "ORDERS", firestoreOrderDetails);
        }

    }
}

public partial class MyOrdersPage : ContentPage
    {
        OrdersViewModel _orderViewModel;
        public MyOrdersPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = _orderViewModel = new OrdersViewModel();
        }
    }

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Instance = this;
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            //Syncfusion.XForms.Android.PopupLayout.SfPopupLayoutRenderer.Init();            
            LoadApplication(new App());       
        }
        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {          
            // Check the NavigationStack count if its equal 1 this means that it is on the rootPage
            int NavStackCount = App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count;
            if (NavStackCount == 1)
            {
                long currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

                if (currentTime - lastPress > 5000)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Press back again to exit", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    lastPress = currentTime;
                }
                else
                {
 
                    base.OnBackPressed();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnBackPressed();
            }
        }
}
```

Everytime App is exited through back button and user opens the app again,Mainactivity created again, MyOrdersPage is created again and so a new OrdersViewModel is created again. Previous OrdersViewModel is still not destroyed as evident from the calls received because of the subscribed events.

Comment: Everything should be destroyed when you exit the app.  Are you sure you’re not just backgrounding it?

Comment: 1) When user returned to app, did app's `OnCreate` get called again [happens when app is destroyed], or was ONLY `OnResume` called [returning from background]? 2) What exactly did you do to determine that a new viewmodel was created, but the old one still existed? 3) Are you using `Shell` (AppShell)? or `NavigationPage`? Or setting `MainPage = new SomePage();` directly? 4) Whatever logic you need to run when viewmodel is destroyed, could you instead put it in `OnPause`?

Comment: 1) OnCreate is callled where new App is loaded again. 2) ViewModel subscribes to some events through MessageCenter .  The viewmodel gets these events multiple times. The count informs the number of vewmodel created.

Comment: I think you are jumping to a wildly incorrect conclusion.  Please post the relevant code and specific behavior that you are basing this on

Comment: Added code in description.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unsubscribe the instances of your MessagingCenter on disposal’s of your ViewModels like:

```
public class OrdersViewModel
{ 
       public OrdersViewModel()
       {
        .
        .
       }

       ~OrdersViewModel()
       {
           MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<IRepositoryService, List<FirestoreOrderDetail>>(this, "ORDERS");
       }

   public async Task ExecuteLoadOrdersCommand()
       {
        .
        .
        .
       }
}
```

---

ALTERNATE OPTION

---

This is the most safe way to handle & unsubscribe the Messagingcenter events. Just unsubscribe the event before subscribing to new events, it will make safe sure that no any other connected subscriptions is existing. Even if there are no any subscribed events, it won't break or throw any exception, so its safe.

```
public class OrdersViewModel
{ 
        public OrdersViewModel()
        {
            // Unsubscribe the events before new subscribing  
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<IRepositoryService, List<FirestoreOrderDetail>>(this, "ORDERS");

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IRepositoryService, List<FirestoreOrderDetail>>(this, "ORDERS", (s, o) =>
            {
                Task.Run(() => LoadOrders(o));
            });
        
            Task.Run(() => ExecuteLoadOrdersCommand());
        }

    public async Task ExecuteLoadOrdersCommand()
        {
         .
         .
         .
        }
}
```

Comment: Which method/event is there for disposal of viewmodel? Moreover subscribe thing is a indicator that class is not disposed.

Comment: `~`+ClassName this acts like disposal & gets called when the application is closed.

Comment: Check the updated answer, Place the method `~OrdersViewModel` (destructor) below your constructor.

Comment: Destructor is not called. This also indicates that viewmodel is not destroyed at all. Note that I am talking about exting app by pressing backbutton. If you close app normally then everything should be fine.

Comment: Okay then try to Unsubscribe the events before new subscription. Its safe

Comment: To unsubscribe form previous instance of viewModel we need the reference to that instance and more importantly the point is that there may be lot of unused instances of a viewmodel which are no longer in use and occupy memory.

Comment: Which type of instance you mentioning about? You just need to Unsubscribe before every Subscribe, you will have all the references there you are subscribing from there itself! And you have to subscribe the Messaging Center just once, if you are doing it from multiple places then that's the main issue, you need to centralize them all. Paste your complete code above from where you are subscribing & sending the even, as the code above doesn't seem to have any issue

Comment: Constructor is only called when a new instance is being created and we need to pass 'this' to unsubscribe. So the previous instance which is not destroyed will not get chance to unsubscribe. Moreover the important point is that the instances are  not destroyed . So all the app's viewmodels instances will keep on accumulating in memory if user keeps using the app for some days and exiting through back button only.  Regarding the code , its somewhat complete code in terms of the issue I am noticing. I wondering what other way to use viewmodel in xamarin.

Comment: @anand have you tried the above logic & it didn’t worked for you or you just making assumptions on logical theories?
As far as I know it works % without any issues, Unsubscribe before Subscription & for additional Unsubscribe in destructor

Comment: My bad i changed the unscribe event `MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<IRepositoryService, List<FirestoreOrderDetail>>(this, "ORDERS");`. Before I missed `, List<FirestoreOrderDetail>` part. The unsubscribe event must be exactly the same as subscribe event. Try the change I uses the same logic & this works perfectly fine for me

Comment: @anand found this as the ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52162831